# Cómo hago un append de un li entre dos li?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, lista

Este es el append que deseo hacer en JS. Es un li que tiene un a tag adentro.
Estoy utilizando bootstrap para hacer un "pagination" donde hago un append de días que llamo desde un JSON.

```
$("#timeline-dias").append("<li value=\""+split[1]+"-
"+split[0]+"-"+diaOrdenado[d]+"T"+horaFecha[h]+"Z\"><a 
href=\"#\">"+diaOrdenado[d]+"</a></li>");
```

Lo deseo hacer entre dos li

```
<ul class="pagination timeline-dias" id="timeline-dias">

  <li>
    <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  ---- aqui quiero hacer el append---

  <li>
    <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es siempre en la penúltima posición? En tal caso te serviría añadir `.insertBefore('#timeline-dias li:last-child');`.

Lo inserta en el último hijo de `li` que haya dentro de `#timeline-dias`

```
$("#timeline-dias").append("<li value=\""+split[1]+"-
 "+split[0]+"-"+diaOrdenado[d]+"T"+horaFecha[h]+"Z\"><a 
  href=\"#\">"+diaOrdenado[d]+"</a></li>").insertBefore('#timeline-dias li:last-child');
```

Es siempre en la segunda posición? Pues lo mismo pero con `.insertAfter()` y `:first-child`

```
$("#timeline-dias").append("<li value=\""+split[1]+"-
     "+split[0]+"-"+diaOrdenado[d]+"T"+horaFecha[h]+"Z\"><a 
      href=\"#\">"+diaOrdenado[d]+"</a></li>").insertAfter('#timeline-dias li:first-child');
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa el [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) en lugar de append.

```js
$( "<li>AAAAAA</li>" ).insertAfter( $( ".primero" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination timeline-dias" id="timeline-dias">

  <li class="primero">
    <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="segundo">
    <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Entiendo. Y por que darle la clase de primero o segundo al a...no deberia ser al li?

Comment: @anabellag7 si perdon, eso se me ha colado ami :P

Comment: @anabellag7 Échale un vistazo también a mi respuesta, ya que no hace falta añadir clases. Y te sirve para añadir más de un sólo elemento.

Comment: @Flowen he añadido el html suyo a tu respuesta para que fuese ejectable y casca. Si tiene buena pinta, ¿pero podrias hacerla funcionar porfa?

Comment: Estoy teniendo un problema mas grave ahora, se carga el pagination cuando refresco la pagina pero cuando termina de cargar, desaparece.

Comment: Al inspeccionar el codigo en la web, los li desaparecen por completo.

Comment: Actualiza tu mensaje o abre una nueva pregunta, ya que el problema ahora ha cambiado. (si actualizas añade abajo, para que las respuestas sigan valiendo).